# Would the torque required by a motor differ depending on where it connects to a frame?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Given a motor attached to a flat surface, aligned to the axis of a laptop screen and connected to the screen via an L shaped arm which is also connected to the motor shaft

Would the torque required by the motor differ depending on the distance from the axis the arm is attached to the laptop screen?

Comment: If we assume that the power needed to rotate the shaft itself is negligible then the answer is no. [This question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149314/does-screwdriver-length-matter) is relevant.